# Laravel Validation sometimes rules for date validation

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-5

I currently have a validation rule which looks like this:

```
  public function rules()
  {
   return [
        'startDate' => 'required|sometimes|before_or_equal:endDate',
        'endDate' => 'sometimes|required|after_or_equal:startDate',
    ];
  }
```

The sometimes option works as I understand it on the basis that if the field is present, run the validation rule. However, if the end date is not sent or is null, my before or equal rule kicks in and fails. In some instances within my application, end date will be null. Is there a way to 'cancel' the startDate validation rule in this instance or would I need to create a custom validator for this purpose?

something like `before_or_equal_when_present` ?

Comment: Could you not just delete the `before_or_equal` since the endnote has to be after the start date if it is present. If this is true, the start date has to also be before the end date. So if the endDate is present and it is before the start date, the after_or_equal rule would already kick in.

Comment: @milo526 - doh! yes, that would work. logic fail on my part there I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use IFs to add and manipulate rules in the rules function. You can access the inputs there referring to $this as the request itself:

```
public function rules()
  {
   $rules = [
        'startDate' => 'required|sometimes|before_or_equal:endDate',
        'endDate' => 'sometimes|required|after_or_equal:startDate',
    ];

   if( $this->input('endDate') > 0)
          $rules['endDate'] = "rule". $rules['endDate']

   return $rules;
}
```

This is just a mockup just to let you know that you can manipulate and have access to the fields passed.